# Can't connect to Amazon Aurora (MySQL) with AWS Schema Conversion Tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-sct

I am having difficulty establishing a connection to my database on AWS. Making the Instance publicly accessible didn't change anything nor was changing the Security Group's inbound to accept any IP coming from MYSQL/Aurora. Here's the error coming from SCT:

```
2018-05-17 15:59:29.655 [  87]     GENERAL INFO    Test connecting to Amazon Aurora (MySQL compatible) database started...
2018-05-17 16:00:11.679 [  87]      LOADER ERROR   Connection to 'jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' wasn't established. ERROR: code: 0; message: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2018-05-17 16:00:11.679 [  87]     GENERAL INFO    Test connecting to Amazon Aurora (MySQL compatible) database finished in 0:00:42.023 sec with memory consumption of 644.93 MB (625.5 MB .. 644.93 MB).
2018-05-17 16:00:11.679 [  87]     GENERAL INFO    Test connecting to Amazon Aurora (MySQL compatible) database statistics:
    GENERAL: 0:00:42.023 sec
2018-05-17 16:00:11.680 [  18]     GENERAL ERROR   com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.launcher.CommonTaskLauncher.lambda$run$0(CommonTaskLauncher.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.setState(Task.java:696)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.lambda$call$501(Task.java:1453)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
    at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:341)
    at com.amazon.sct.handler.CreateConnectionHandler.createConnection(CreateConnectionHandler.java:37)
    at com.amazon.sct.viewmodel.AppViewModel.createConnection(AppViewModel.java:1198)
    at com.amazon.sct.viewmodel.AppViewModel.createTargetConnection(AppViewModel.java:769)
    at com.amazon.sct.view.AppView.loadTarget(AppView.java:283)
    at com.amazon.sct.view.AppView.lambda$initConnectionMenusBindings$22(AppView.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.checkConnection(DbLoader.java:655)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.initLoader(DbLoader.java:507)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.getDbLoader(DbLoader.java:739)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:31)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:14)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 1 more
```

I've also tried using SQL Workbench/J and received the following error:

> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

What else should I attempt to solve this issue?

Comment: You found the solution for it ?